# Props asyncData Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a Parent component where I take a id and I want to send to Child component.

In this Child component I have a asyncData function and it is calling an API.

The code:

```
<script>
export default defineNuxtComponent({
props:["membersId"];
setup(props) {
    const userId = props.membersId;
        return{
             userId,
        };
    },
    
async asyncData(){
    const id = userId;
    const users = await $fetch(`API/${id}`);
        return {users}
}
    
});
    
</script>
```

How can I pass the prop inside asyncData with this code? At this moment is not working because the Lifecycle hooks.

Thanks